# How can I continue range if there is exception in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

This is my piece of code at the moment:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

driver = uc.Chrome()

def open_next():
    try:
        driver.get(next(urls))
    except StopIteration:
        return

try:
    for i in range(amount):
        open_next()
        button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div')
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
except NoSuchElementException:
    print('Failed. Try again.')
else:
    pass
```

I need to add new string `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/table').click()` after `open_next()` and if this element is not finding code should continue working.

What i tried so far? I try to add second `except NoSuchElementException` and this is how it looks:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

driver = uc.Chrome()

def open_next():
    try:
        driver.get(next(urls))
    except StopIteration:
        return

try:
    for i in range(amount):
        open_next()
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/table').click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
except NoSuchElementException:
    print('Failed. Try Again.')
else:
    pass
```

When I start code, It's skip my new string, click at the button and then execute `pass` even though there is more amount of urls. What should I use to solve this problem? My code skip `for i in range(amount)`

Comment: If you want the loop to continue if there is an exception you need to put the `try/except` block **inside** the for loop. In your code, you have the opposite: the loop is inside the `try` block.

Comment: can you please provide some example how it can be possible? when i try to put except inside the for loop it gives me syntax error as output

Answer (score 0):

Try the following script:

```py
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

driver = uc.Chrome()

def open_next():
    try:
        driver.get(next(urls))
    except StopIteration:
        return


for i in range(amount):
    try:
        open_next()
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/table').click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div')
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('Failed. Try Again.')
    else:
        pass
```

The try/expect needs to be inside the for-loop